# Splitting a movie clip in in the video editor with this encoding seems to desync audio and video

Tags: rendering, video, audio

Blender version 3.2.0
Clip ffmpeg info:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MAH00059.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : MSNV
    minor_version   : 22675568
    compatible_brands: MSNVmp42isom
    creation_time   : 2022-06-06T20:59:16.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:30.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3063 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2932 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-06-06T20:59:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-06-06T20:59:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

The clip is an mp4 file at 23.98 fps as seen above. Adding the video clip is fine as the audio sequence and video sequence line up fine visually in the sequence editor. However, splitting the clip (shortcut K) seems to cause a problem. After rendering, the output video clearly jumps back a few frames at the split and is slightly out of sync with the audio. I went back and tried the same process but first created a 25%, 50 quality proxy before splitting at some point on the clip. This time the frame jump back at the split was terrible and caused a massive desync between the audio and video.

Since I did not have any audio and video sync problems on a previous video I made with 50+ mkv video files, I tried transcoding the original mp4 to an mkv file with:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mkv
```

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'MAH00052.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: MSNVmp42isom
    MAJOR_BRAND     : MSNV
    MINOR_VERSION   : 22675568
    ENCODER         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:00:41.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3049 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : Video Media Handler
      VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
      ENCODER         : AVC Coding
      DURATION        : 00:00:41.041000000
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : Sound Media Handler
      VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
      DURATION        : 00:00:41.024000000
```

I followed the same procedures for the mkv file of adding the clip and splitting it with and without the proxy, and then rendering. On the rendered output video, no matter with or without the proxy, the audio and video were perfectly in sync before and after the split.

I see two problems:

1. Splitting and mp4 encoded clip caused frames to jump back on the split after rendering
2. Using a proxy exacerbated the problem significantly

Could this be a bug with how mp4 encoding on blender 3.2.0 is handled?

[Blender Proxy/Timecode Doc](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/editors/clip/sidebar.html) says:
"A proxy is a smaller image (faster to load) that stands in for the main image. When you rebuild proxies Blender computes small images (like thumbnails) for the big images and may take some time. After computing them, though, editing functions like scrubbing and scrolling is much faster but gives a low-res result. Make sure to disable proxies before final rendering."

Check these link to see the behavior I am referring to: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19kgHzF_ZtQNFx0FScrPELom_CsYaZD6x/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L56YtShAf7pggUIg9ktMVpJgvUVGMBTg/view?usp=sharing